# N: Ignoring file 'opera.listV' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

How can I fix this i just converted from windows please dont go hard on me lol

Actually i get longer error code when i hit `sudo apt update` however after i hit `apt list --upgradeable`

I only get `N: Ignoring file 'opera.listV' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension`

But When i hit `sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                         

Hit:2 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                      

Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease

Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease

Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

N: Ignoring file 'opera.listV' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (non-free/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (non-free/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1

W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do: `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list{V,}`. `apt` wants files ending in `.list`. Other file extensions are regarded as a potential error. If `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.listV` is an error, `rm` it.